# Change minimum zoom level of poi-label Native Layer of Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio, mapbox-vector-tile

I'm currently working on a project that requires us to utilize the "poi-label" native layer of mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8 tileset of Mapbox.

Currently, I've noticed that only a few POIs from the "poi-label" layer are represented on zoom level 12, while more POIs become visible on zoom level 13 and beyond. I understand that this may be due to optimizing map rendering. However, for specific project requirements, we need to display a significantly higher number of POIs on zoom level 10 instead of zoom level 12.
I have a couple of questions regarding this issue:

1. How can we display more POIs on zoom level 10?
2. In the documentation of mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8, the min-zoom level for poi_label is stated as 5. Why can't we see these POIs on zoom level 10 as expected?

These are what I tried:

1. In Mapbox Studio, within my style, on the Select Data tab, I attempted to change the min-zoom to 10 or 9. However, I could not see the desired increase in POIs on zoom level 10.
2. I also tried to override the minzoom property of the "poi-label" layer using the following code:

`map.getLayer("poi-label").setMinZoom(10);`